# Shell Script to modify a text file for SQL usage

Tags: shell

I have some text file to process.
Sample input:

```
'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'ww',   'Keeper'
'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'aw',   'Seeker'
'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'iw',   'Left Beater'
'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'sw',   'Right Beater'
```

Can someone tell me how to add `{ ....... },` at both ends of each line using shell script?

Sample output:

```
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'ww',   'Keeper'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'aw',   'Seeker'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'iw',   'Left Beater'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'sw',   'Right Beater'},
```

Comment: awk '{printf("{%s}",$0)' < input > output

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) with a regular expression to put the whole line into a matching group, then replace it surrounding it with curly braces and a comma at the end.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/{\1},/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Without redirecting the output you get:

```
> sed 's/\(.*\)/{\1},/g' input.txt 
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'ww',   'Keeper'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'aw',   'Seeker'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'iw',   'Left Beater'},
{'Edmonton Event',   '2013-11-16-14.00.00',  'WW',   'sw',   'Right Beater'},
```

Comment: thanks, just find out how to use simple shell script and it works perfectly, but my code took 5 lines.